# Widget wont refresh with setstate sfcalendar custom agenda

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, state-management, sfcalendar

The Picture shows how it should look like.
But in my App, the agenda is inside a TAB!

[image: this is how it schould look like at the end. except my agenda is inside a Tab]Can anyone tell me why my code wont work?

I am trying to display data from DataSource but it wont show up!
(SFCalendar - Custom Agenda)

(Basically - to get it to show my appointments in a separate widget "far up the tree" <onTap: calendarTapped>)

I recreated the code on github since its too much code for stackoverflow - i guess its easier with vcs anyway:

https://github.com/panval/sfcalcustagenda.git

I simply can't manage to get it to work!
What am I missing?

Comment: what would be your expected out, maybe you can create a minimal snippet and include on question

Comment: @YeasinSheikh - sure - I edited my question. Maybe you can find a solution. 
I recon it's something about state -(I'm new to coding - this might be an easy solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You arent passing the selected item on `Tabs` widget. You can use constructor the way you did for `CustomAgenda`.

```dart
class Tabs extends StatefulWidget {
  Tabs({Key? key, required this.appointmentDetails});
```

and use

```dart
   CustomAgenda(appointmentDetails: widget.appointmentDetails),
```

You can remove the state variable from here.

Comment: Tried, failed. :(
Unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Comment: merge [this pr](https://github.com/panval/sfcalcustagenda/pull/1)  and click on different dates to check the output

Comment: thank you for taking your time to do this.
My coding skills are at that point where I have no Idea how to merge from github.
syncfusion just replied a couple minutes ago and they solved this issue.

Comment: you can click and search about git, it will be  necessary for any dev.